# looking for NRPE services code

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I am looking for the NRPE services code that allow to connect to the remote host to check :-

1. http service connect on port 80 or custom port
2. ssh service on port 22 or custom port
3. since the check disk code compatible with hda , i need check disk
   compatible with sda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use NRPE plugins to check remotely accessible resources/services like HTTP and SSH. You can just use check_http and check_ssh plugins available with nagios.

For the check_disk, I think it should support both devices' namings (hda or sda).

Answer (score 0):

NRPE configuration is found in the /etc/nagios directory (on Ubuntu at least).

To change the check_disk command, edit the relevant file in that directory (probably nrpe.cfg) and change it to use /dev/sda instead of /dev/hda.

For the other services, create relevant commands that will perform the checks you want, e.g.:

```
command[check_my_web_server]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H www.example.com # and whatever you want for the return
```

Run /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http --help for options and examples.

Answer (score 0):

NRPE can run all of the same plugins that nagios can run. So, your host with the NRPE daemon can run check_http, check_ssh, etc., against other hosts. This is useful if you have a single host behind a firewall/NAT that you want to check other hosts that it can see (but are unavailable from the nagios hosts's view).

As far as checking sda: see the output of check_disk --help

check_disk can use device names, filesystem mountpoints, or regular expressions that match either of these.

By default, it will check all disks (anything that's in mtab, actually. this includes shm, devfs, tmpfs, etc.)